# Power BI Icons based on previous day values

Tags: powerbi

I have matrix table in PBI as follows:

[image]

I would like the icons to be red if the value of the previous day is less than the current day column and green if it is higher but looking at the PB options I am not seeing a clear way to do that:

[image]

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you just need to be a little creative.

Create a calculated column to calculate the difference from the previous day. e.g.

```
Delta = CALCULATE(SUM (Sheet1[Value])) - CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Value]), 
                                                   PREVIOUSDAY(Sheet1[Date]), ALL(Sheet1))
```

Then base your conditional formatting on the calculated column. You need to base the condition on numbers, not the default percentages and then have conditions for 0, -99999999 to 0 and 0 to 99999999.

**Sample Visual**
[image: Sample Visual]

**Conditional Formatting**
[image: Conditional Formatting]